# Duplicating a Class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, duplicates, clone

I have a movieClip in my library called blueBox, with a corresponding class, blueBox.as, which holds the blueBox() constructor, some variables and a function to handle a MOUSE_DOWN event. I also have a movieClip called redBox that needs a almost identical class to blueBox.as. Is it possible to duplicate blueBox.as, changing only the name of the constructor and the value of a variable without doing so manually and saving it as redBox.as? It isn't a big problem doing it manually for now, but as this project grows, it will create a meaningless amount of files, all containing the same information and this seems a bit redundant, any insight welcome.

Comment: You can't change name of constructor. Describe precisely what you want to do. It seems that you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need a Box class that can display different types of movie clips. Once you have that class you can create multiple instances of it each with a different movieclip(redBox,blueBox etc.)

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but how can I do this when I can not have more than one externally visible definition of the file, nor link two movieCLips to the same class?

Comment: I assume you are using Flash Professional to do this, I don't use it so my knowledge is limited, but you should be able to export your assets (redbox,bluebox) movieclips in a swf and then write a separate AS3 class to use those.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how this would be done, sorry. I guess I am stuck with things as they are, it is no big problem to be honest, I just thought it was a bit redundant to have several identical files, but it seems flash disagrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) -- a concept that you are already using by extending from the `MovieClip` class. When you inherit from a class, you are borrowing it's implementation, and you can add more specific functionality to it, or even override a super-classes implemenation.

Let's look at a contrived example:

Given have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class BlueBox extends MovieClip {

    private var color:uint;

    public function BlueBox() {
        this.color = 0x0000FF;
        this.addEventListener(MosueEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handler)

        redraw();
    }

    // Mouse handler
    private function handler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("DOWN!");
    }

    // some internal work
    private funciton redraw() {
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.beginFill(this.color);
        this.graphics.drawRect(10,10,50,50);
    }

    // other methods.
}
```

And you want to make a very similar `RedBox` class that changes `color` to be `0xFF0000`.

So right now, `BlueBox` inherits its functionality from `MovieClip`. This means that its a more "specific" sub-type. `MovieClip` itself inherits from `Sprite`, borrowing some work from that class and extending it itself.

In fact, there is an entire hierachy of inheritance for a `MovieClip`:

```
MovieClip -> Sprite -> DisplayObjectContainer -> InteractiveObject -> DisplayObject -> EventDispatcher  -> Object
```

You can see that the most basic type is `Object`, which *almost* all things are in ActionScript. "Almost" is the key word in that sentence.

Probably the easiest way to achieve is to create a parent class -- or base class -- that both `BlueBox` and `RedBox` will inherit from. This new parent will hold the code that is common between them, then `RedBox` and `BlueBox` will only contain the code that is distinct between them.

For example, lets look at the new base class:

```
public class AbstractBox extends MovieClip {

    private var color:uint;

    public function AbstractBox(color:uint) {
        this.color = color;
        this.addEventListener(MosueEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handler)
        redraw();
    }

    // Mouse handler
    private function handler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("DOWN!");
    }

    // some internal work
    private funciton redraw() {
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.beginFill(this.color);
        this.graphics.drawRect(10,10,50,50);
    }

    // other methods.
}
```

Notice this class `AbstractBox` contains most of the same stuff as before: it inherits from `MovieClip`, it has the `handler` and `redraw` functions. Really the only difference is that its constructor accepts one argument -- the color it will use to draw the rectangle in `redraw`.

So what can we remove from `BlueBox`? Pretty much everything, lets take a look:

```
public class BlueBox extends AbstractBox {
    public function BlueBox(color:uint) {
        super(0x0000ff)
    }
}
```

Notice that `BlueBox` now extends `AbstractBox`, and most of its implementation has been removed -- or more specifically borrowed from its super. Inside the constructor we call our "parent" classes constructor and give it the color that it should use.

Now to make `RedBox`, all we have to do is change the color:

```
public class RedBox extends AbstractBox {
    public function BlueBox(color:uint) {
        super(0xff0000)
    }
}
```

There you go. The code common to both lives in `AbstractBox`, and then `RedBox` and `BlueBox` are just specific implementations of that common ancestor.

This is pretty much just the tip of the iceberg when it comes to OOP, there is still a lot to learn and -- perhaps more importantly -- learning when *not* to use inheritance to solve a problem. But, luckily for you, there are a lot of resources on the internet for gaining those skills.

---

Based off your comment, you could try another approach as long as you are instatating these DisplayObjects from actionscript -- and not from the Flash UI -- would be to use a static method, rather than sub classes to generate them

```
public class AbstractBox extends MovieClip {

    public static function createBlueBox():AbstractBox
    {
        return new AbstractBox(0x0000FF);
    }

    public static function createRedBox():AbstractBox
    {
        return new AbstractBox(0xFF0000);
    }

    private var color:uint;

    public function AbstractBox(color:uint) {
        this.color = color;
        this.addEventListener(MosueEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handler)
        redraw();
    }

    // Mouse handler
    private function handler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("DOWN!");
    }

    // some internal work
    private funciton redraw() {
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.beginFill(this.color);
        this.graphics.drawRect(10,10,50,50);
    }

    // other methods.
}
```

And then invoke them using:

```
var blue:AbstractBox = AbstractBox.createBlueBox();
var red:AbstractBox = AbstractBox.createRedBox();
```

The Flash UI requires an inheritance chain and a parameterless constructor on the classes that you reference, so if you are linking your clips that way then you have to generate children classes. Or change paradigms completely and not rely on the constructor to setup/change the property in question, but have the clip redraw itself once a property has been set. Something like:

```
public class AbstractBox extends MovieClip {

    private var _color:uint;

    public function get color():uint { return _color; }
    public function set color(val:uint) {
        _color = val;
        redraw();
    }

    public function AbstractBox() {
        this.addEventListener(MosueEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handler)
        redraw();
    }

    // Mouse handler
    private function handler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("DOWN!");
    }

    // some internal work
    private funciton redraw() {
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.beginFill(this.color);
        this.graphics.drawRect(10,10,50,50);
    }

    // other methods.
}
```

Notice that setting the `.color` property will cause the MovieClip to redraw itself.

```
redBox.color = 0xFF0000; // where redBox is an instance name of an AbstractBox in the Flash UI.
blueBox.color = 0x0000FF;
```

Comment: You guess at my code sample was pretty good, and I already using inheritance to at least lessen the files for each separate movie clip. I just thought there might be a way to eliminate the need for a separate class file for each object altogether, while still having code in the constructor. Sorry for my unclear opening post.